# How to resolve Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very annoying problem to solve. I have a method that searches for a code of a sale, it is:

```
  public function findByCode(string $code, string $columns = "*"): ?Sales
    {
        $find = $this->find("code = :code", "code={$code}", $columns);
        return $find->fetch(true);
    }
```

When I try to call him that:

```
$sales = (new Sales())->findByCode(client()->code);
```

It shows me the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Source\Models\Sales::findByCode() must be an instance of Source\Models\Sales or null, array returned in**

How to solve this?

Comment: I assume the `$find->fetch(true);` is returning a row of some data, have you made sure that the fetch function inserts the data into a Sales object and returns that new object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making the `findByCode` function restrict to return data with type `Sales` and when you are using `return $find->fetch(true);` it will return some array of that's type is not compatible with `Sales` so PHP is complaining here about that. so just make a new object of `Sales` and return it.

The code should be some thing like this:

```
 public function findByCode(string $code, string $columns = "*"): ?Sales
 {
        $find = $this->find("code = :code", "code={$code}", $columns);
        $result = $find->fetch(true);
        return new Sales($result);
 }
```

So the `Sales` class can get the data and assign them to its properties and act as a `DTO` or something.